# JQuery UI DatePickers: troubles when set min/max Date

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I should reset min/max date at datepicker:

```
$(item).datepicker('option', 'minDate', null);
```

**Problem:** after that string datepickers date disappears. I.e. datepicker had "Mar 01, 2014" date, than after the string above it'll have no date.

*Important:* That happen at Firefox 31.0, but at Chrome all works well.

**Question:** How to set minDate in a correct way? Is that Firefox bug?

Comment: It seems to be fine here? http://jsfiddle.net/MelanciaUK/7t137tp8/

Comment: @MelanciaUK thanks for example. Yes, it's all right with your example, but unfortunately my app is broken by that damn string. Seems I need to do more investigations. Also is there any other ways do delete minDate restriction?

Comment: @MelanciaUK I'll check and tell you in 2-3 hours the jquery-ui version I use in my app

Comment: @MelanciaUK `$.ui.version` echoes `1.8.20`

Comment: Looks fine still: http://jsfiddle.net/MelanciaUK/7t137tp8/2/